# Java+Selenium+Cucumber не видит definition class

Tags: java, maven, selenium, cucumber

Привет. Я забилдил простейший проект в Eclipse и все работало, потом конвертнул в мавен и теперь при прогоне получаю вот это:

1 Scenarios ([33m1 undefined[0m)
1 Steps ([33m1 undefined[0m)
0m0.000s

You can implement missing steps with the snippets below:

```
@Given("^I navigate to webpage$")
public void i_navigate_to_webpage() throws Throwable {
    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
    throw new PendingException();
}
```

При этом, дефинишн класс конечно же имеется.

Мой раннер класс:

```
package runner;

import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;
import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(features="features")
public class Runner {

}
```

Definition class

```
package stepDef;

import org.junit.Assert;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxBinary;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxProfile;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

import java.io.File;
import java.nio.file.*;

import cucumber.api.java.After;
import cucumber.api.java.en.Given;
import cucumber.api.java.en.Then;
import cucumber.api.java.en.When;
import model.PageModel;

public class Definition {

    WebDriver driver;
    PageModel pagemodel;
    WebDriverWait wait;

    @Given("^I navigate to webpage$")
    public void i_navigate_to_webpage() throws Throwable {

        String url;


        url = Helper.getPropValue("landing", "navigation");
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "src.stepDef");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();    
        pagemodel = new PageModel(driver);
        wait=new WebDriverWait(driver,45);          
         driver.get(url);
         driver.manage().window().maximize();

         WebElement whatWe = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(pagemodel.webHome));
         Assert.assertTrue(whatWe!=null);

    }


}
```

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>MyTest</groupId>
  <artifactId>MyTest</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.7.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>2.53.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.4</version>
    </dependency>
   <dependency>
    <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.5</version>
  </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Провел весь день в гугле - ответа нет. Только вопросы от таких же чудиков как я.
Кто нибудь сталкивался с таким?
Сердце мне подсказывает что надо все сносить и делать заново, но хотелось бы разобраться

Comment: первый кусочек кода, где `throw new PendingException();`, это существующий метод у вас в проекте?  приложите к вопросу полный трейс, нажав на править

Comment: скопировал весь оутпут выше. Метод существующий, он там тоже есть, помечен как Definition class

Comment: не могли бы написать путь до класса Definition ?

Comment: MyTest/src/runner/Definition.java

Comment: то есть не в src/test/, верно?

Comment: нет, не там. а это важно?

Comment: попробовал с src/test/Definition.java - все то же самое, дефинишн не находится

Answer (score 0, accepted):

скорее всего у вас неправильная структура проекта. Класс Definition находится не в /src/test/java

в `/src/test/resources/` кладем features-файл

`Runner.class` и `Definition.class` должны лежать в `/src/test/java/.../`

p.s. в pom.xml не хватает зависимости junit, если не ошибаюсь

**UPDATE**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Смотрите внимательно на картинку. Runner и Definition находятся в папке тестов, фиче-файл - в ресурсах.

Для раннера нужно указывать, где находятся все фиче-файлы, либо конкретный

```
package example;

import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;
import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(features="./src/test/resources/features/ff.feature")
public class Runner {

}
```

можно также указывать `classpath:cucumber/features/ff.feature`

Comment: перенес в src/test/java/ - то же самое

Comment: junit вроде есть     <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.4</version>
    </dependency>

Comment: обновил ответ. посмотрите и попробуйте

Comment: Не помогло. а если использовать класспас classpath:/features/test.feature то вообще не находит фича файл

Comment: No features found at [classpath:/features/test.feature]

0 Scenarios
0 Steps
0m0.000s

Comment: потому что надо использовать `classpath:features/test.feature`

Comment: No features found at [classpath:features/test.feature]

0 Scenarios
0 Steps
0m0.000s

Comment: О, заработала сабачка )))) Спасибо огромное!

Comment: всегда пожалуйста, сообщество всегда поможет вам, если вы не ленитесь. Если данный ответ решил вашу проблему, то можно принять ответ как верный, нажав на галочку рядом с ответом